# how to programatically trigger "Start DLQ Redrive"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs, dlq

In my application we are using aws SDK along with Nodejs, i have a source queue and DLQ Queue, i need to programatically trigger "Start DLQ Redrive", Through the console it is pretty strighforward, but how we can trigger this programatically, i couldnt able to find a documentation or code example for this, can anyone help me find a code example or documentation releated to it

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DLQ Redrive is a feature only available in the AWS Console and not provided in the CLI at this time.

You can make a DLQ replay using a tool like `replay-aws-dlq`  (https://github.com/garryyao/replay-aws-dlq) or `sqsmover` (https://github.com/mercury2269/sqsmover).

You can use `replace-aws-dlq` like this:
`npx replay-aws-dlq https://sqs.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/ACCOUNT_ID/DLQ_SQS_QUEUE_ID https://sqs.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/ACCOUNT_ID/ORIGIN_SQS_QUEUE_ID`.

Comment: can i use replay-aws-dlq inside a nodejs application. the example you are showing is like running from command prompt

Comment: Of course you can. My example with replace-aws-dlq is running a Node.js application under the hood that you can replicate, using the source code provided by the GitHub repository.

Answer (score 1):

AWS launched [DLQ redrive SDK and CLI support](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/a-new-set-of-apis-for-amazon-sqs-dead-letter-queue-redrive/) in Jun this year, so you can programatically trigger it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35012041)